# Does Migration Mode cause a server to run at lesser capacity than normal?

Tags: migration, windows-sbs-2011

I'm not going to get too much into the issue I am having with SBS 2011 Essentials, but in a nutshell, we performed a successful migration. However, the OS is still in migration mode (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Server\Setup registry key states everything is completed but the MigrationMode value is still set to true, as is the UnattendedInitialConfig value).

I plan on setting these to false in a few hours and rebooting once the rest of the office goes home, but I am curious to know if a server performing in migration mode is running in a hampered state other than not being able to access the Dashboard?